# Query that provides the names of the recruiters that hire more than 3 employees, and the number of employees that were not hired by a recruiter

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join, group-concat

I'm a bit stuck on this question and was hoping for some help. Here's where I'm at currently.

I have this TEST table of Names. Each Person can either be a recruiter or an employee. The number in Recruited_by is associated with the person_id.

```
Person_id   Name    Recruited_by

1   Jean Grayson    1    
2   Paul Smith      7    
3   John Do         Null    
4   Alex Lee        7    
5   Lisa Kim        7    
6   Bob Thompson    3    
7   Mike Keen       Null    
8   Raymond Red     3    
9   Alisson Jones   1    
10  Kate James      3
```

Here is the query I have so far which I'm trying to the names of the recruiters that hire more than 3 employees (which will return nothing in this case) and the number of employees that were NOT recruited by anyone (which would be the NULL names).

```
SELECT T.Name as Employees, COUNT(T1.Name) as Not_hired
FROM Test AS T
WHERE COUNT(T1.Name) IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN Test AS T1
ON T.Recruited_by = T1.Person_id
GROUP BY T.Name
HAVING COUNT(T1.Name) > 3
```

However this query is returning nothing when I should expect it to return the number of employees who were not hired by a recruiter!

Comment: Aggregate function isn't used in WHERE clause. Please place the WHERE clause after ON clause and without aggregate. Please provide expected output.

Comment: You are asking for 2 different results that can't be combined. What is your expected result?

Comment: @RahulBiswas I'm expecting to see something one column that will say Name which would be Null and another column that would say Not_hired which would have display the numeric value 2.

Comment: If there are 5 recruiters that hired more than 3, then there would be 5 rows in the results with the 5 names in 1 column and the number 2 in the other column 5 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want in the results only 1 row with 2 columns then you can do  a LEFT join of the table to a query that aggregates to get the ids of the persons that hired more than 3 persons and aggregate again to get the number of persons that were not recruited by anyone:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN t2.Recruited_by IS NOT NULL THEN t1.Name END ORDER BY t1.Name) names,
       SUM(t1.Recruited_by IS NULL) total_not_recruited
FROM Test t1 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT Recruited_by
  FROM Test
  GROUP BY Recruited_by
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
) t2 ON t2.Recruited_by = t1.Person_id;
```

You will get the names of the persons that hired more than 3 persons (if they exist) as a comma separated list.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e1421ba4d4c17c674f8f1ef4158b8a3).